# Is there data available on the amount of questions posted over time?

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

I've noticed that the amount of questions posted on BSE has sky rocketed. That's implying a sudden rise in the interest in Blender? If I'm not mistaken, the [first ever question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-soft-body-balloons-from-crumpling-when-they-hit-walls) on BSE was posted 10 years ago or more than 100,000 questions ago. I remember 2 or 3 months ago we reached 100,000 questions and now are suddenly up 10% to almost 110,000 in such a short period of time. We will be at 200,000 questions in no time. I was wondering if there was data on this available, like a chart we could view of the amount of questions posted over time?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Data Stack Exchange API](https://data.stackexchange.com/) will let you build SQL Queries to get whatever stats you want about a stack exchange site.

I don't know enough about SQL to build one, but [Bill the Lizard](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337184/number-of-questions-for-each-year) already did the ground work for us, so I adapted to get the number of questions per month per year.

```
SELECT count(Id), MONTH(CreationDate), YEAR(CreationDate)
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 1
  GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
  ORDER BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
```

You can test it at https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/1774167/total-questions-per-month-year

After extracting the output CSV file into a spreadsheet editor we can compute a partial sum column.

| Year | Month | Questions | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013 | May | 138 | 138 |
| 2013 | Jun | 262 | 400 |
| 2013 | Jul | 164 | 564 |
| 2013 | Aug | 188 | 752 |
| 2013 | Sep | 174 | 926 |
| 2013 | Oct | 179 | 1105 |
| 2013 | Nov | 213 | 1318 |
| 2013 | Dec | 265 | 1583 |
| 2014 | Jan | 285 | 1868 |
| 2014 | Feb | 294 | 2162 |
| 2014 | Mar | 306 | 2468 |
| 2014 | Apr | 333 | 2801 |
| 2014 | May | 325 | 3126 |
| 2014 | Jun | 312 | 3438 |
| 2014 | Jul | 344 | 3782 |
| 2014 | Aug | 329 | 4111 |
| 2014 | Sep | 324 | 4435 |
| 2014 | Oct | 445 | 4880 |
| 2014 | Nov | 393 | 5273 |
| 2014 | Dec | 479 | 5752 |
| 2015 | Jan | 600 | 6352 |
| 2015 | Feb | 562 | 6914 |
| 2015 | Mar | 618 | 7532 |
| 2015 | Apr | 547 | 8079 |
| 2015 | May | 676 | 8755 |
| 2015 | Jun | 586 | 9341 |
| 2015 | Jul | 685 | 10026 |
| 2015 | Aug | 817 | 10843 |
| 2015 | Sep | 656 | 11499 |
| 2015 | Oct | 658 | 12157 |
| 2015 | Nov | 643 | 12800 |
| 2015 | Dec | 705 | 13505 |
| 2016 | Jan | 805 | 14310 |
| 2016 | Feb | 753 | 15063 |
| 2016 | Mar | 771 | 15834 |
| 2016 | Apr | 712 | 16546 |
| 2016 | May | 823 | 17369 |
| 2016 | Jun | 827 | 18196 |
| 2016 | Jul | 848 | 19044 |
| 2016 | Aug | 804 | 19848 |
| 2016 | Sep | 827 | 20675 |
| 2016 | Oct | 896 | 21571 |
| 2016 | Nov | 801 | 22372 |
| 2016 | Dec | 757 | 23129 |
| 2017 | Jan | 907 | 24036 |
| 2017 | Feb | 815 | 24851 |
| 2017 | Mar | 862 | 25713 |
| 2017 | Apr | 769 | 26482 |
| 2017 | May | 664 | 27146 |
| 2017 | Jun | 769 | 27915 |
| 2017 | Jul | 967 | 28882 |
| 2017 | Aug | 934 | 29816 |
| 2017 | Sep | 827 | 30643 |
| 2017 | Oct | 856 | 31499 |
| 2017 | Nov | 831 | 32330 |
| 2017 | Dec | 771 | 33101 |
| 2018 | Jan | 848 | 33949 |
| 2018 | Feb | 856 | 34805 |
| 2018 | Mar | 942 | 35747 |
| 2018 | Apr | 810 | 36557 |
| 2018 | May | 921 | 37478 |
| 2018 | Jun | 832 | 38310 |
| 2018 | Jul | 874 | 39184 |
| 2018 | Aug | 838 | 40022 |
| 2018 | Sep | 823 | 40845 |
| 2018 | Oct | 760 | 41605 |
| 2018 | Nov | 827 | 42432 |
| 2018 | Dec | 925 | 43357 |
| 2019 | Jan | 1137 | 44494 |
| 2019 | Feb | 1061 | 45555 |
| 2019 | Mar | 1100 | 46655 |
| 2019 | Apr | 1052 | 47707 |
| 2019 | May | 916 | 48623 |
| 2019 | Jun | 904 | 49527 |
| 2019 | Jul | 1098 | 50625 |
| 2019 | Aug | 1413 | 52038 |
| 2019 | Sep | 1146 | 53184 |
| 2019 | Oct | 1047 | 54231 |
| 2019 | Nov | 1070 | 55301 |
| 2019 | Dec | 1117 | 56418 |
| 2020 | Jan | 1228 | 57646 |
| 2020 | Feb | 1182 | 58828 |
| 2020 | Mar | 1296 | 60124 |
| 2020 | Apr | 1423 | 61547 |
| 2020 | May | 1556 | 63103 |
| 2020 | Jun | 1638 | 64741 |
| 2020 | Jul | 1505 | 66246 |
| 2020 | Aug | 1386 | 67632 |
| 2020 | Sep | 1313 | 68945 |
| 2020 | Oct | 1283 | 70228 |
| 2020 | Nov | 1245 | 71473 |
| 2020 | Dec | 1231 | 72704 |
| 2021 | Jan | 1381 | 74085 |
| 2021 | Feb | 1390 | 75475 |
| 2021 | Mar | 1398 | 76873 |
| 2021 | Apr | 1249 | 78122 |
| 2021 | May | 1197 | 79319 |
| 2021 | Jun | 1161 | 80480 |
| 2021 | Jul | 1196 | 81676 |
| 2021 | Aug | 1085 | 82761 |
| 2021 | Sep | 1082 | 83843 |
| 2021 | Oct | 985 | 84828 |
| 2021 | Nov | 983 | 85811 |
| 2021 | Dec | 1161 | 86972 |
| 2022 | Jan | 1470 | 88442 |
| 2022 | Feb | 1069 | 89511 |
| 2022 | Mar | 1255 | 90766 |
| 2022 | Apr | 1244 | 92010 |
| 2022 | May | 1145 | 93155 |
| 2022 | Jun | 1126 | 94281 |
| 2022 | Jul | 1165 | 95446 |
| 2022 | Aug | 1306 | 96752 |
| 2022 | Sep | 1139 | 97891 |
| 2022 | Oct | 1167 | 99058 |
| 2022 | Nov | 1130 | 100188 |
| 2022 | Dec | 1159 | 101347 |
| 2023 | Jan | 1192 | 102539 |
| 2023 | Feb | 1147 | 103686 |
| 2023 | Mar | 1130 | 104816 |
| 2023 | Apr | 1009 | 105825 |
| 2023 | May | 1065 | 106890 |
| 2023 | Jun | 946 | 107836 |
| 2023 | Jul | 1109 | 108945 |
| 2023 | Aug | 194 | 109139 |

Using your favorite office suite you can then build a beautiful line chart.

[image: Blender Stack Exchange Total Questions per year line chart 2023]

Comment: Nice! thanks for your answer! very cool that we can query different types of data.

Comment: Very interesting. We can say in hindsight that the Blender team and community had a great impact on the hearsay for the 2.8 version (around 2020). Of course we can also suppose that the number has been inflated due to worldwide events at the time but the trend makes sense. FWIW here's the query (I think) for number of answers per month/year https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/revision/1791006/2175136/total-answers-per-month-year

Comment: It was indeed a turning point, 2.8 made Blender become more "mainstream", and brought a huge influx of new people. It was released in 2019, though, but you can see the effects of its beta ramping up as early as 2018 already. 2020 consolidated the growth with the pandemics and a lot of people locked up at home with extra time on their hands to dedicate to new hobbies. Thanks for the query, gotta sharpen my skills in SQL, seems like a useful tool